# What is the best way to check if a specific plugin is installed and enabled from a helper class?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, helper

My helper class has a plugin-dependecy and I'd like to double check if that plugin is installed and enabled, what is the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried using `ProjectConfiguration::getActive()` methods, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I have added the following function to my `ProjectConfiguration` class:

```
public function hasPluginEnabled($pluginName)
{
    return in_array($pluginName, $this->getPlugins());
}
```

I was suprised that this isn't already included in symfony 1.4 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `ProjectConfiguration::getPlugins()`? It should return an array with loaded plugins.